# Why does my VBA script change the date format?

Tags: vba, excel, datepicker

I have a script set on a button so that it copies the date from a cell (put in by a date picker linked to the cell) to another cell in a different worksheet.

My problem is that I want the date format to always be `dd/mm/yyyy`. At the moment, if I pick a date that is say `"28/03/2014"` then it will copy this date over exactly as it is. The issue comes when I pick a date like `"02/03/2014"`, this will now for some reason be converted to `"03/02/2014" (mm/dd/yyyy format)` when copied across. I don't know why it is happening and even more so, why it is only happening for dates that 'could' be correct either format.

This is the code I am using to copy the date:

```
Worksheets("ActionPlan").Range("E" & (ActiveCell.Row)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Worksheets("ActionPlan").Range("E" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = Worksheets("Update").Range("G3").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I hadn't declared the array storing the value as a Date before copying it. I had it stored as an integer and was trying to convert it to a date after copying it.

I have now declared "dtValue" as a Date before transferring the date from cell G3 into to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

After copying the data add this line of code to modify the format back to what you want:

```
  Range("G7").NumberFormat = "m/d/yy;@"
```

To figure out the code you could use the macro recorder

Comment: Would reversing my 2 lines of code not do the same thing?
What does the ';@' at the end of the line of code you suggest do?

Comment: the line of code I've printed comes from the macro recorder. Its a random format. You should record a macro to figure out what code you need

Comment: I followed your advise and recorded a macro. IT suggested to use "dd/mm/yyy;@" so that's what I used and I still have the same issue.